# Outlook Express Add-in

Tags: add-in, outlook

I'm wondering is it any add in/plug in SDK for Outlook Express.
  As i know, we can use COM addin or VSTO to develop our own plugin for MS Outlook. So how about addin for Outlook Express.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Outlook express is now called windows mail. You are limited to what you can do with is compared to VSTO.

The pubished API's are at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709546(VS.85).aspx

I am not sure what the lastest is but I thought that they were pulling it in it latest guise.

I you are looking for a more rad tool and managed code 
http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-outlook-express/ 
is probally the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

The alternatives are:

1. Look at the ["Reading and Writing Messages in Outlook Express" article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/Outlook_Express_Messages.aspx).
2. Use the [Add-In-Express IDE integration of Nektra's OEAPI](http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-outlook-express/).
3. Use the Nektra's OEAPI for [Outlook Express & Windows Mail](http://www.nektra.com/products/oeapi-windows-mail-outlook-express-plugin/) and WLMailApi for [Windows Live Mail API](http://www.nektra.com/products/wlmailapi-windows-live-mail-api-plugin-2011-support-2009-legacy-support). (Disclosure: I work for Nektra).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlook_Express#Extensibility) on Outlook Express; specifically the "Extensibility" section of the article.

Looks like there's a GPLd example of a PGP plugin, so you might start there.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my blog which provides detail about what is VSTO and how to create plugin for Outlook using C# and visual studio 
officedevs.wordpress.com

Comment: Are we supposed to search for your blog? Don't you want to tell us where it is?